# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object for Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, json

I have data that deserialises fine when I retrieve a single entry of data however,

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Purchaseorderline]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

this is to retrieve Orders and OrderItems, I can do a single order (by requesting a single order number) however when I get all orders, it errors, 
I have performed the standard converting to Json objects to ensure my class is correct and cannot see what Im supposed to apply as an array to my class to simply put it into a List of type RootObject..

Here is my Code:

```
      {
                // ... Read the string.
                var result1 = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                List<Rootobject> POOrders = new List<Rootobject>();
                Rootobject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result1);
                POOrders.Add(test);
                POOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(result1);
             }
```

here is the class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using SFOrders;

public class Rootobject:Purchaseorderline
{
     [JsonProperty("PurchaseOrderID")]
    public string PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PurchaseOrderGuid")]
    public string PurchaseOrderGuid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("User")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderReference { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("DateRaised")]
    public DateTime DateRaised { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Supplier")]
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Warehouse")]
    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("DateDue")]
    public DateTime DateDue { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("PurchaseOrderStatus")]
    public string PurchaseOrderStatus { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("DeliveryCost")]
    public float DeliveryCost { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Subtotal")]
    public float Subtotal { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalVat")]
    public float TotalVat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Total")]
    public float Total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Currency")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("DateSent")]
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("PurchaseOrderLines")]
    public Purchaseorderline[] PurchaseOrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("UserID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
     [JsonProperty("SupplierID")]
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{

    [JsonProperty("WarehouseName")]
    public string WarehouseName { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("WarehouseGuid")]
    public string WarehouseGuid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("WarehouseID")]
    public int WarehouseID { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
     [JsonProperty("CurrencyID")]
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CurrencyCode")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("CurrencyName")]
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
}

public class Purchaseorderline
{
    [JsonProperty("PurchaseOrderLineID")]
    public int PurchaseOrderLineID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ProductSKU")]
    public string ProductSKU { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("QtyOrdered")]
    public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("QtyReceived")]
    public int QtyReceived { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PurchaseOrderDetailStatus")]
    public string PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("SinglePrice")]
    public float SinglePrice { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("LineVat")]
    public float LineVat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("LineTotal")]
    public float LineTotal { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("DeliveryStatusID")]
    public int DeliveryStatusID { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("QtyWrittenOff")]
    public float QtyWrittenOff { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CartonQty")]
    public int CartonQty { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("AddedByUserID")]
    public int AddedByUserID { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("TotalUnitsOrdered")]
    public int TotalUnitsOrdered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalUnitsReceived")]
    public int TotalUnitsReceived { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("TotalUnitsWrittenOff")]
    public int TotalUnitsWrittenOff { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("LineNotes")]
    public string LineNotes { get; set; }



     [JsonProperty("TotalItems")]
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("PagingInfo")]
    public object PagingInfo { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("TotalPages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public SFOrders.SFOrderData.Datum[] Data { get; set; }


}
```

and here is the raw data:

```
{
   "TotalItems":2,
   "PagingInfo":{
      "PageSize":100,
      "Page":1
   },
   "TotalPages":1,
   "Data":[
      {
         "PurchaseOrderID":21179,
         "PurchaseOrderGuid":"89bb1056-4d26-42a2-bf9c-25962637b42e",
         "User":{
            "UserID":10169,
            "UserName":"Viv Williams"
         },
         "PurchaseOrderReference":"1-test-1",
         "DateRaised":"2017-03-03T00:00:00",
         "Supplier":{
            "SupplierID":1307,
            "Name":"99A  Avery Warehouse"
         },
         "Warehouse":{
            "WarehouseName":"Charlies Direct",
            "WarehouseGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "WarehouseID":122
         },
         "DateDue":"2017-03-04T00:00:00",
         "PurchaseOrderStatus":"SentToSupplier",
         "DeliveryCost":0.0000,
         "Subtotal":0.0000,
         "TotalVat":0.0000,
         "Total":0.0000,
         "Currency":{
            "CurrencyID":4,
            "CurrencyCode":"GBP",
            "CurrencyName":"British Pound"
         },
         "DateSent":"2017-03-03T12:13:59.05",
         "PurchaseOrderLines":[
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184694,
               "ProductSKU":"065233",
               "QtyOrdered":3,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":3,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            },
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184695,
               "ProductSKU":"039586",
               "QtyOrdered":10,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":10,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            },
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184696,
               "ProductSKU":"009493",
               "QtyOrdered":2,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":2,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            },
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184697,
               "ProductSKU":"002836",
               "QtyOrdered":5,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":5,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "PurchaseOrderID":21180,
         "PurchaseOrderGuid":"854c1c5a-f63b-490e-99dc-119ed298988a",
         "User":{
            "UserID":10169,
            "UserName":"Viv Williams"
         },
         "PurchaseOrderReference":"2 add Tues",
         "DateRaised":"2017-03-03T00:00:00",
         "Supplier":{
            "SupplierID":1298,
            "Name":"99D  Dyffryn Warehouse"
         },
         "Warehouse":{
            "WarehouseName":"Charlies Direct",
            "WarehouseGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "WarehouseID":122
         },
         "DateDue":"2017-03-04T00:00:00",
         "PurchaseOrderStatus":"SentToSupplier",
         "DeliveryCost":0.0000,
         "Subtotal":0.0000,
         "TotalVat":0.0000,
         "Total":0.0000,
         "Currency":{
            "CurrencyID":4,
            "CurrencyCode":"GBP",
            "CurrencyName":"British Pound"
         },
         "DateSent":"2017-03-03T12:13:48.19",
         "PurchaseOrderLines":[
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184698,
               "ProductSKU":"003010",
               "QtyOrdered":5,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":5,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            },
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184699,
               "ProductSKU":"094508",
               "QtyOrdered":12,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":12,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            },
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184700,
               "ProductSKU":"003820",
               "QtyOrdered":20,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":20,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            },
            {
               "PurchaseOrderLineID":184701,
               "ProductSKU":"003823",
               "QtyOrdered":4,
               "QtyReceived":0,
               "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus":"AwaitingProduct",
               "SinglePrice":0.0000,
               "LineVat":0.0000,
               "LineTotal":0.0000,
               "DeliveryStatusID":1,
               "QtyWrittenOff":0.0,
               "CartonQty":1,
               "AddedByUserID":10169,
               "TotalUnitsOrdered":4,
               "TotalUnitsReceived":0,
               "TotalUnitsWrittenOff":0,
               "LineNotes":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your JSON is not formatted properly.

The `Data` element should be an array rather than an object.

The following should do:

```
{
   "TotalItems":2,
   "PagingInfo":{
      "PageSize":100,
      "Page":1
   },
   "TotalPages":1,
    "Data": [
        {
            "PurchaseOrderID": 21179,
            "PurchaseOrderGuid": "89bb1056-4d26-42a2-bf9c-25962637b42e",
            "User": {
                "UserID": 10169,
                "UserName": "Viv Williams"
            },
            "PurchaseOrderReference": "1-test-1",
            "DateRaised": "2017-03-03T00:00:00",
            "Supplier": {
                "SupplierID": 1307,
                "Name": "99A Avery Warehouse"
            },
            "Warehouse": {
                "WarehouseName": "Charlies Direct",
                "WarehouseGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "WarehouseID": 122
            },
            "DateDue": "2017-03-04T00:00:00",
            "PurchaseOrderStatus": "SentToSupplier",
            "DeliveryCost": 0.0000,
            "Subtotal": 0.0000,
            "TotalVat": 0.0000,
            "Total": 0.0000,
            "Currency": {
                "CurrencyID": 4,
                "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                "CurrencyName": "British Pound"
            },
            "DateSent": "2017-03-03T12:13:59.05",
            "PurchaseOrderLines": [
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184694,
                    "ProductSKU": "065233",
                    "QtyOrdered": 3,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 3,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184695,
                    "ProductSKU": "039586",
                    "QtyOrdered": 10,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 10,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184696,
                    "ProductSKU": "009493",
                    "QtyOrdered": 2,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 2,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184697,
                    "ProductSKU": "002836",
                    "QtyOrdered": 5,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 5,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PurchaseOrderID": 21180,
            "PurchaseOrderGuid": "854c1c5a-f63b-490e-99dc-119ed298988a",
            "User": {
                "UserID": 10169,
                "UserName": "Viv Williams"
            },
            "PurchaseOrderReference": "2 add Tues",
            "DateRaised": "2017-03-03T00:00:00",
            "Supplier": {
                "SupplierID": 1298,
                "Name": "99D Dyffryn Warehouse"
            },
            "Warehouse": {
                "WarehouseName": "Charlies Direct",
                "WarehouseGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "WarehouseID": 122
            },
            "DateDue": "2017-03-04T00:00:00",
            "PurchaseOrderStatus": "SentToSupplier",
            "DeliveryCost": 0.0000,
            "Subtotal": 0.0000,
            "TotalVat": 0.0000,
            "Total": 0.0000,
            "Currency": {
                "CurrencyID": 4,
                "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                "CurrencyName": "British Pound"
            },
            "DateSent": "2017-03-03T12:13:48.19",
            "PurchaseOrderLines": [
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184698,
                    "ProductSKU": "003010",
                    "QtyOrdered": 5,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 5,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184699,
                    "ProductSKU": "094508",
                    "QtyOrdered": 12,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 12,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184700,
                    "ProductSKU": "003820",
                    "QtyOrdered": 20,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 20,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184701,
                    "ProductSKU": "003823",
                    "QtyOrdered": 4,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 4,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If the `Data` element should not be an array, in that case your JSON contains extra values and the following should be what you are looking for:

```
{
   "TotalItems":2,
   "PagingInfo":{
      "PageSize":100,
      "Page":1
   },
   "TotalPages":1,
    "Data": 
        {
            "PurchaseOrderID": 21179,
            "PurchaseOrderGuid": "89bb1056-4d26-42a2-bf9c-25962637b42e",
            "User": {
                "UserID": 10169,
                "UserName": "Viv Williams"
            },
            "PurchaseOrderReference": "1-test-1",
            "DateRaised": "2017-03-03T00:00:00",
            "Supplier": {
                "SupplierID": 1307,
                "Name": "99A Avery Warehouse"
            },
            "Warehouse": {
                "WarehouseName": "Charlies Direct",
                "WarehouseGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "WarehouseID": 122
            },
            "DateDue": "2017-03-04T00:00:00",
            "PurchaseOrderStatus": "SentToSupplier",
            "DeliveryCost": 0.0000,
            "Subtotal": 0.0000,
            "TotalVat": 0.0000,
            "Total": 0.0000,
            "Currency": {
                "CurrencyID": 4,
                "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                "CurrencyName": "British Pound"
            },
            "DateSent": "2017-03-03T12:13:59.05",
            "PurchaseOrderLines": [
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184694,
                    "ProductSKU": "065233",
                    "QtyOrdered": 3,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 3,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184695,
                    "ProductSKU": "039586",
                    "QtyOrdered": 10,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 10,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184696,
                    "ProductSKU": "009493",
                    "QtyOrdered": 2,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 2,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                },
                {
                    "PurchaseOrderLineID": 184697,
                    "ProductSKU": "002836",
                    "QtyOrdered": 5,
                    "QtyReceived": 0,
                    "PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus": "AwaitingProduct",
                    "SinglePrice": 0.0000,
                    "LineVat": 0.0000,
                    "LineTotal": 0.0000,
                    "DeliveryStatusID": 1,
                    "QtyWrittenOff": 0.0,
                    "CartonQty": 1,
                    "AddedByUserID": 10169,
                    "TotalUnitsOrdered": 5,
                    "TotalUnitsReceived": 0,
                    "TotalUnitsWrittenOff": 0,
                    "LineNotes": ""
                }
            ]
        }

}
```

Comment: I cant change the Json as its from a supplier API call..? Ive changed my class to be just an array of object    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public object[] Data { get; set; }             but no joy Im afraid,

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because you are trying to deserialize your JSON string into a list of Rootobjects instead of Rootobject itself.

Also generate your classes by copying the JSON string (the complete one) and pasting it via Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes in Visual Studio.

Here is the Rootobject:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public Paginginfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Paginginfo
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderGuid { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRaised { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDue { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderStatus { get; set; }
    public float DeliveryCost { get; set; }
    public float Subtotal { get; set; }
    public float TotalVat { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public Purchaseorderline[] PurchaseOrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{
    public string WarehouseName { get; set; }
    public string WarehouseGuid { get; set; }
    public int WarehouseID { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
}

public class Purchaseorderline
{
    public int PurchaseOrderLineID { get; set; }
    public string ProductSKU { get; set; }
    public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }
    public int QtyReceived { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderDetailsStatus { get; set; }
    public float SinglePrice { get; set; }
    public float LineVat { get; set; }
    public float LineTotal { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryStatusID { get; set; }
    public float QtyWrittenOff { get; set; }
    public int CartonQty { get; set; }
    public int AddedByUserID { get; set; }
    public int TotalUnitsOrdered { get; set; }
    public int TotalUnitsReceived { get; set; }
    public int TotalUnitsWrittenOff { get; set; }
    public string LineNotes { get; set; }
}
```

But if your JSON string contains an array of Rootobjects, something like this:

```
[{RawData1},{RawData2},{RawData3}]
```

then you can deserialize it as follows:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(json);
```

Comment: I gathered that because I can contain a list of a single RootObject, Im struggling to get it do work when there are multiples of the same object in the Json.. that's where the error comes in, I have done it before on an example API (the Telerik soap Test API emulator) and that works fine.. but I really struggle to get the data out the Json into a list...?

Comment: I just tested my code with an array. It works fine. How did you generate your classes?

Comment: I just copied the raw data into clipboard, created a class, paste special and paste Json as classes... then put the JsonProperty on each one...

Comment: Ive just recreated the class again , still the same.. how did you test your array ?

Answer (score 0):

Slept on it... it was similar to what your answer was Mahdi thankyou, 
I needed to deserialise the Raw, then foreach through the deserialised object to add it to a list,

```
  Rootobject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result1);
               foreach(Rootobject  items in test.Data)
               {
                   POOrders.Add(items);
               }
```